# Как исправить слетание кодировки при обработке jsonl в json файла

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, utf-8

Я конвертирую jsonl в json, но при выведении таблицы слетает кодировка

```
import pandas as pd    
jsonObj = pd.read_json(path_or_buf='/NTI_data/test.jsonl', lines=True)
print(jsonObj)

output:
                                                                             passage  
0    {'text': '"(1) Р�Р·РґР°С‚РµР»СЊСЃС‚РІРѕ Viking Press СЃРѕРІРјРµСЃС‚РЅРѕ СЃ Р...  
1    {'text': '"(1) РЎС‚СѓРґРёСЏ Epic Games Р°РЅРѕРЅСЃРёСЂРѕРІР°Р»Р° Р±РµС‚Р°-С‚Р...  
2    {'text': '"(1) РљРѕРјРїР°РЅРёСЏ Warner Bros. СЂР°СЃСЃРјР°С‚СЂРёРІР°РµС‚ Р‘Рµ...  
3    {'text': '(1) РќР° РїРѕР»РєР°С… Р»Р°Р±РѕСЂР°С‚РѕСЂРёРё Р›РѕСѓСЂРµРЅСЃ-Р‘РµСЂ...  
4    {'text': '(1) РЈСЃРёР»РёСЏ Р›СЌРЅРіРґРѕРЅР° РѕРєР°Р·С‹РІР°СЋС‚СЃСЏ РЅР°РїСЂР...  
..                                                                               ...  
317  {'text': '(1) РљР°РєРѕРµ Р¶Рµ Р·РµСЂРєР°Р»Рѕ Р¶РёР·РЅРё РЅР°С€ СЏР·С‹Рє!(2) ...  
318  {'text': '(1) Р РѕСЃСЃРёСЏРЅРёРЅ Р”РјРёС‚СЂРёР№ РњРёС…Р°Р№Р»РµРЅРєРѕ СЃС‚Р°Р...  
319  {'text': '(1) Р”Р°С‚СЃРєРёР№ РєР°СЂРёРєР°С‚СѓСЂРёСЃС‚ РљСѓСЂС‚ Р’РµСЃС‚РµСЂР...  
320  {'text': '(1) Р–РёР»-Р±С‹Р» РјР°Р»РµРЅСЊРєРёР№ РјРµРґРІРµР¶РѕРЅРѕРє. (2) РЈ ...  
321  {'text': '"(1) Р’ Р›Р°С‚РІРёРё РІС‹РЅРµСЃРµРЅ РїСЂРёРіРѕРІРѕСЂ РІР»Р°РґРµР»С...
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте параметр `encoding`:

```
import pandas as pd    
jsonObj = pd.read_json(path_or_buf='/NTI_data/test.jsonl', lines=True, encoding='utf-8')
print(jsonObj)
```